# How to get all function names that are used in whole request

Tags: python, flask, datadog

I have an API that is calling multiple functions and I need to know how many functions are calling into that so i can send that information into datadog server.

I got one solution as

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def log_function_calls(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('Function called: %s', func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

This is the function.

I have to use that function

```
def say_hello():
   print("hello")

@log_function_calls
def get():
 def say_hello()
```

By doing this i'm able to get all the names

but for that i have to add decorator in every funcion.

- I'm using Flask Framework with class based api calling

**I want to create a common function that returns me how many functions are used in the whole request**

> In @after_request function

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a context manager to set a profile and log function calls as following. You can add the functions for which you want the name logged under FunctionCallLogger().

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


class FunctionCallLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.setprofile(self.log_function_calls)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.setprofile(None)

    def log_function_calls(self, frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'call':
            func_name = frame.f_code.co_name
            args = frame.f_locals
            self.logger.debug(f"Function '{func_name}' called with args: {args}")
        return self.log_function_calls


def say_hello():
    print("hello")


def say_hi():
    print("hi")


with FunctionCallLogger():
    say_hello()
    say_hi()
```

Here, we define a FunctionCallLogger class that implements the context management protocol. The **init** method creates a logger object that will be used to log information about function calls.

The **enter** method sets the profile using the sys.setprofile method to call the log_function_calls method, which logs information about function calls.

The **exit** method disables the profile by setting it to None. This is done to ensure that the profiling does not interfere with any other code after the context has been exited.

The **log_function_calls** method logs information about function calls. It takes three arguments: **frame**, **event**, and **arg**. The frame argument is a stack frame object that contains information about the current function call. The event argument is a string that indicates the type of event (e.g., 'call', 'return', etc.). The arg argument is the argument passed to the function call.

Comment: But for this i need to add all functions into with FunctionCallLogger():
i want to create a common function that gives me how many functions was in that whole API

In @after_request

Comment: You can try using something like OpenTelemetry. https://opentelemetry.io/